# Is it possible to look at two consecutive rows and determine the difference in time between the two using SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am relatively new to SQL, so please bear with me! I am trying to see how many customers make a purchase after being dormant for two years. Relevant fields include `cust_id` and `purchase_date` (there can be several observations for the same `cust_id` but with different dates). I am using Redshift for my SQL scripts.

I realize I cannot put the same thing in for the `DATEDIFF` parameters (it just doesn't make any sense), but I am unsure what else to do.

```
SELECT  *
FROM tickets t
     LEFT JOIN d_customer c
     ON c.cust_id = t.cust_id
WHERE     DATEDIFF(year, t.purchase_date, t.purchase_date) between 0 and 2
ORDER BY t.cust_id, t.purchase_date
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `lag()`.  To get the relevant tickets:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             LAG(purchase_date) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY purchase_date) as prev_pd
      FROM tickets t
     ) t
WHERE prev_pd < purchase_date - interval '2 year';
```

If you want the number of *customers*, use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id)
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             LAG(purchase_date) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY purchase_date) as prev_pd
      FROM tickets t
     ) t
WHERE prev_pd < purchase_date - interval '2 year';
```

Note that these do not use `DATEDIFF()`.  This counts the number of *boundaries* between two date values.  So, 2018-12-31 and 2019-01-01 have a difference of 1 year.

Comment: thanks! But suppose I now have two ticket lists I want to join. ```SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id)
FROM (SELECT  * FROM f_ticket_lifecycle
      where cust_id not in (-1,-2)
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT  * FROM f_ticket_lifecycle_cur
      where cust_id not in (-1,-2) 
     ) t
 (SELECT t.*,
             LAG(purchase_date) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY purchase_date) as prev_pd
      FROM tickets t
     ) t
WHERE prev_pd < purchase_date - interval '2 year';``` I keep getting syntax errors, but I have tried this among other things.

Comment: @dte324 . . . New questions should be asked as *questions* not as *comments*.  This question is clearly about one `tickets` table.